# Cypress - passing object to cy.type or cy.contains command

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I'm generating name and surname, which I want to use them in several it tests. With describe block I save them into JSON file. Then I want to use them in cy.type or cy.contains.

```
describe("Constants", function () {
const uuid = () => Cypress._.random(0, 1e3)
const suid = () => Cypress._.random(0, 1e3)
const id = uuid()
const sid = suid()
const Firstname = `Test${id}`
const Surname = `Patient${sid}`
it("Copy constants", function () {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/constants.json', { "Firstname" : Firstname, "Surname" : Surname})
})
```

})

When I use both variables in it test, they're represented as object (see picture)

```
it('Treatments', function() {
      cy.visit('/')
      cy.fixture("constants.json").then(ime => {   
        cy.log(ime.Firstname)
      cy.fixture("constants.json").then(priimek => {   
        cy.log(priimek.Surname)
      cy.get('a.ng-tns-c80-4').click()
      cy.get('path[d="M19 11h-6V5a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v6H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h6v6a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-6h6a1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"]').click()
      cy.get('.d-flex > .appearance-filled').should('be.visible').and('contain','Create').click()
      //Patient info
      cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.patientInformationTitle"]').should('be.visible').and('contain','Patient information')
      cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.errors.firstNameIsRequired"]').should('be.visible').and('contain','First name is required!')
      cy.get('#firstName').should('be.visible').clear().type(`${ime}`)
      cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.errors.lastNameIsRequired"]').should('be.visible').and('contain','Last name is required!')
      cy.get('#lastName').should('be.visible').clear().type(`${priimek}`)
```

})

[Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pucIL.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```js
it('Treatments', function () {
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.get('a.ng-tns-c80-4').click()
  cy.get(
    'path[d="M19 11h-6V5a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v6H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h6v6a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-6h6a1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"]'
  ).click()
  cy.get('.d-flex > .appearance-filled')
    .should('be.visible')
    .and('contain', 'Create')
    .click()

  //Patient info
  cy.fixture('constants.json').then((ime) => {
    cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.patientInformationTitle"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'Patient information')
    cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.errors.firstNameIsRequired"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'First name is required!')
    cy.get('#firstName').should('be.visible').clear().type(ime.Firstname)
    cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.errors.lastNameIsRequired"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'Last name is required!')
    cy.get('#lastName').should('be.visible').clear().type(ime.Surname)
  })
})
```

Or, You can have the fixture file in the `beforeEach()` and then use it throughout the test:

```js
describe('Test Suite', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    // "this" points at the test context object
    cy.fixture('constants.json').then((constants) => {
      // "this" is still the test context object
      this.constants = constants
    })
  })

  it('Treatments', function () {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('a.ng-tns-c80-4').click()
    cy.get(
      'path[d="M19 11h-6V5a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v6H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h6v6a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-6h6a1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"]'
    ).click()
    cy.get('.d-flex > .appearance-filled')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'Create')
      .click()

    //Patient info
    cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.patientInformationTitle"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'Patient information')
    cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.errors.firstNameIsRequired"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'First name is required!')
    cy.get('#firstName')
      .should('be.visible')
      .clear()
      .type(this.constants.Firstname)
    cy.get('[translate="treatmentsPage.errors.lastNameIsRequired"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('contain', 'Last name is required!')
    cy.get('#lastName')
      .should('be.visible')
      .clear()
      .type(this.constants.Surname)
  })
})
```